# Docker: unable to run any container - cannot allocate memory: unknown

Tags: linux, docker, server

I'm trying to setup docker on my server but am running into the following error even when I try to run the demo 'hello-world' image:

```
docker run hello-world

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply cgroup configuration: mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/246b9b461a8341391ad376c88ab923274c924d96c109762f06940be65ff82b17: cannot allocate memory: unknown.
```

This is running on an ubuntu 20.04 server with 4gb ram, 4 core cpu and 480gb ssd storage.

`top` output:

```
Tasks:  31 total,   1 running,  30 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   4096.0 total,   3742.6 free,     99.2 used,    254.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    512.0 total,    512.0 free,      0.0 used.   3995.6 avail Mem
```

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop30740p1  449G  5.6G  425G   2% /
none               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              410M  1.2M  409M   1% /run
tmpfs              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /tmp
tmpfs              410M     0  410M   0% /run/user/0
```

The server seems to have more than enough memory and free disk and swap space.

I've tried rebooting the server, restarting the docker engine but had no luck. I then reinstalled the os and upgraded to ubuntu 22.04, installed the latest docker engine but am experiencing the exact same issue.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you resolved it already? @marko

Comment: @GithendraMcShane Not really, the resolution that a bunch of forums suggested was tu turn off swap completely, however this was not possible on my hosting so i transfered everything on the host machine as it made sense for my projects size and i needed to solve the problem asap.